# ionic + cordova plugin and background mode

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making an app with ionic for car drivers. The app takes coordinates every one minute and write them on remote server, this helps me to tracking route and show cars on Google map.

I use Cordova plugin and it works fine except when screen turns off or the app goes into the background. I installed katzer cordova-plugin-background-mode, when the app go into background I see the message : app is now in background, the plugin informs me but nothing else, the app stopped! .

No data sent to remote server, when I resume the app all is back to normal, I use Android platform. How can i solve?

app.js code

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova','LocalStorageModule', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleLightContent();
        }

        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

    });
})
.....
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('GeoCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaNetwork, $http, $interval) {


var reloadCoordinates = function() {

  var watchOptions = {
    timeout : 10000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false // may cause errors if true
  };

  var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);

  watch.then(
    null,
    function(err) {
      // error

    },
    function(position) {
      //Latitudine e Longitudine
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude
      var lon = position.coords.longitude

      $scope.latitude  = lat 
      $scope.longitude = lon


      $http.post('http://192.168.1.2/get-data.php', { "lat": lat, "lon" : lon }).then(function(resp) {
              console.log('Success Lat:'+resp.data.lat+' Lon:'+resp.data.lon);
              watch.clearWatch();

          }, function(err) {
              console.error('ERR', err);
              // err.status will contain the status code
      })

  });


 };//end reloadCoordinates


 $interval(reloadCoordinates, 60000);

 reloadCoordinates();

})
```

Comment: please refer this [link](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/i-found-a-solution-for-some-regular-background-activity/27012) the background activity solved for me when I am using media player to play the songs

Comment: Thanks Anil, I checked and I see that background mode plugin works fine, based on which smartphone button is pressed, for example in my one page app:  Back button -> Exit from app;  Home button -> app go in background and icon appears in the status bar. In both case plugin show the message: App run in background, this can confuse drivers when they will use app

Comment: OK you can do one thing activate the above plugin code when you want to use the maps

Comment: I also faced the same problem, if not i will attach my sample code when i activated and deactivated the plugin

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I did manage to get this working, with:

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('enable', function(){
    //your code here, will execute when background tasks is enabled
    loop();
});

function loop(){
    console.log("loop");
    $timeout(loop, 1000);
}

cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

Comment: maybe a silly question, but where exactly did you put these lines, cause my main bootstrapping class (MyApp) simply doesn't eat it. (sorry I'm new in ionic)

Answer (score 1):

@Cristian,
after enabling plugin, you should call your function or write your logic in this function.

```
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function() {
// your logic here
// or call any other service, factory function
};
```

Comment: that function it is not working, anything that i have put inside of it, doesn´t show up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make an app that does something every x minutes, even when the app is in the background and/or the screen is turned off.... tried backgound-mode plugin but it only works reliably when the phone is plugged in... did you ever found a solution to this?
Install the plugin using the cordova command line utility:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/boltex/cordova-plugin-powermanagement.git
```

here's how i use it along with the background mode plugin so the app is never in background and always running as a service...:

```
if( ionic.Platform.isAndroid() ){
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

window.powerManagement.dim(function() {
  console.log('Wakelock acquired');
}, function() {
  console.log('Failed to acquire wakelock');
});
window.powerManagement.setReleaseOnPause(false, function() {
  console.log('setReleaseOnPause successfully');
}, function() {
  console.log('Failed to set');
});

}
```

Final Step Deactivate your plugin when you finished your service as

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disable()
```